# set a property's value with unknown depth within an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion

```
var params = {
    search: {
        make: "",
        model: ""
    }
}

function setVariable() {
    var value = "BMW";
    var key = "search.make";
    var arr = key.split(".");    //eg. ["search", "make"]
    params[arr[0]][arr[1]] = value;   // this works, but how do you
                                      // do it with unknown arr[] length?
}
```

How do I do this with an unknown `arr[]` length?

I have surmised that I probably need to do a recursive call, maybe passing something like `arr.slice(1)` within the function, but I have not been able to figure out what that should look like.

Comment: What if `search` does not even exist? Would you want to create the object `{make: value}` then and assign it to `params.search`? Or do you only want to be able to set the value for *existing* properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var params = {
    search: {
        make: "",
        model: "",
        whatever: {
            foo: {
                bar: {
                    moo: 123,
                    meow: 'xyz'
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

function updatePath(obj, path, value) {
    var parts = path.split('.');
    var i, tmp;
    for(i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        tmp = obj[parts[i]];
        if(value !== undefined && i == parts.length - 1) {
            tmp = obj[parts[i]] = value;
        }
        else if(tmp === undefined) {
            tmp = obj[parts[i]] = {};
        }
        obj = tmp;
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Demo:

```
> updatePath(params, 'search.whatever.foo.bar')
{ moo: 123, meow: 'xyz' }
> updatePath(params, 'search.whatever.foo.bar.moo')
123
> updatePath(params, 'search.whatever.foo.bar.moo', 'test')
'test'
> updatePath(params, 'search.whatever.foo.bar.moo')
'test'
> updatePath(params, 'search.whatever.foo.bar')
{ moo: 'test', meow: 'xyz' }
> updatePath(params, 'search.whatever.foo.bar.x.y.z', 'hi')
'hi'
> updatePath(params, 'search.whatever.foo.bar.x')
{ y: { z: 'hi' } }
> updatePath(params, 'search.whatever.foo.bar')
{ moo: 'test',
  meow: 'xyz',
  x: { y: { z: 'hi' } } }
>
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code traverses your `params` object until the given key is found. It assumes that `key.split(".")` returns a proper array of keys (so you might need to sanitize your inputs here further.

```
var params = {
    search: {
        make: "",
        model: ""
    }
}

function setVariable() {
    var value = "BMW";
    var key = "search.make";
    var arr = key.split(".");    //eg. ["search", "make"]

    var runner = params;
    for( var i=0, max=arr.length-1; i<max; ++i ) {
       // make sure the key exists
       runner[ arr[i] ] = runner[ arr[i] ] || {};
       // move one level deeper
       runner = runner[ arr[i] ];
    }

    // set the value in the last level
    runner[ arr[arr.length-1] ] = value;   
}
```

**EDIT:** wrt to the comment of Felix Kling: It assumes that you want previously not existant keys to be generated. Else you would have to put a a further check into the `for` loop and leave the function, if the key does not exist, instead of creating it.

Comment: Won't this set the value of the `runner` variable, rather than the original `params` variable?

Comment: As it is always working ob objects, both `runner` and `params` always point to the same object or a part of it respectively. An expression like `runner = 3;` would break this connection, but adding a new key to the object does not. So the above script should add values to the original object after all. [fixing a typo, too]